# Laravel patch external API

Tags: laravel, api, external

I'm getting data from an external API source.

Im using this to retrieve my orders

```php
$data = Http::get(
    $this->URL .'orders?language=nl_NL&limit=100&format=json&status_changed_start_date='
       . $last_poll
       . '&ordering=asc&partner_token='.$this->PARTNERKEY.'&token='.$this->MERCHANTTOKEN.''
)->json();
```

following the guide on the partner site I should use this format to update a specific record.

```
curl -X PATCH $this->URL ."orders/2?language=nl_NL&format=json&override_minimum=false&override_stock=false&mutate_stock=true&partner_token='.$this->PARTNERKEY.'&token='.$this->MERCHANTTOKEN.'" \
     -H  "accept: application/json" \
     -H  "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "{\"status\":2,\"archived\":true,\"comments\":{\"internal\":\"Owner's commentary\"}}"
```

How would I implement this within a Laravel controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client) provide by Laravel:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController
{
    public function update (Request $request)
    {
        // Maybe use from $request?
        $id = 2;

        Http::patch($this->url . "/orders/" . $id, [
            'version' => 1,
            'order_number' => 2,
            'language' => 'nl_NL',
            'format' => 'json',
            'override_minimum' => false,
            // .. put here the other parameters
        ]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code with your suggestions but my API is not accepting this.
Could it be because of these parameters? :

-H  "accept: application/json"  -H  "Content-Type: application/json"
The URL + Query parameters I can adjust but it is more to do with the data part:
-d "{\"status\":2,\"archived\":true,\"comments\":{\"internal\":\"Owner's commentary\"}}"
The URL of the API guide: https://connect.myonlinestore.com/swagger-docs/. It is under Order -> Patch.

Comment: What error does the API return? I updated my answer. You please show your complete code.

Comment: I got error 5000 contact the helpdesk :-)

Comment: This is what I have now.

$responsePatch = Http::patch($this->URL  . '/order/' . $item['number'] .'?language=nl_NL&format=json&override_minimum=false&override_stock=false&mutate_stock=true&partner_token='.$this->PARTNERKEY.'&token='.$this->MERCHANTTOKEN, [
     'status' => '2',
     'archived' => true,//,
     'comments' => [
      'internal' => $this->escaperoomcodes
     ],
   ]
  );

Comment: THx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Here is my final code.

this seems to be working as I needed

```
$client = new Client([
                // Base URI is used with relative requests
                'base_uri' => $this->URL,
            ]);
              
            $response = $client->request('PATCH', 'orders/' . $item['number'] .'?language=nl_NL&format=json&override_minimum=false&override_stock=false&mutate_stock=true&partner_token='.$this->PARTNERKEY.'&token='.$this->MERCHANTTOKEN, [
                'json' => [
                    'status' => 2,
                    'archived' => true,
                    'comments' => ['internal' => $comment]],
            ]);
```